# App freeze for a second when adding map to UI through code behind

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, navigation

I am navigating from one page to another (xamarin forms android device), i am adding a map to UI after some operations and while adding the map to UI, i can feel the UI is flickering for a second. How can we properly add a new view to the page without affecting the performance of the appication

```
public Constructor(string _jobOrderId, JobOrder jobOrderDetails)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);
            vm = new OrderAssignmentDetailsVM();
            this.BindingContext = vm;

        }


protected override void OnAppearing()
        {
            base.OnAppearing();
            ClickEvent();
            SetUiElements();
            GoogleMapData();
            SetMaptoUI();
            List.ItemsSource = vm.OrderStatusList;
        }
```

Adding map to the UI

```
     private void SetMaptoUI()
            {
                //add map to UI
                mapHolder.Children.Add(map);
                mapHolder.Children.Add(new Image() { Source = "redpin.png", HeightRequest = 50, WidthRequest = 33, Margin = Device.OnPlatform(new Thickness(0, 0, 0, 60), new Thickness(0, 0, 0, 25), 0),
                    VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center, HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center });
}
```

How to properly add UI view to the page without affecting the UI performance?

Answer (score 0):

You have to assign your main view after you change elements in grid:

```
Content = null; //now mapHolder is detached from your main view hierarchy

mapHolder.Children.Add(map);
    mapHolder.Children.Add(new Image() { Source = "redpin.png", HeightRequest = 50, WidthRequest = 33, Margin = Device.OnPlatform(new Thickness(0, 0, 0, 60), new Thickness(0, 0, 0, 25), 0),
        VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center, HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center });

Content = mapHolder;
```

Comment: if I make content to null then rest of the views will be removed and only map will be added right?

Comment: It depends what is your view structure. I added example where mapHolder is the root.

Comment: that also a problem, i have other elements in UI

Comment: You can use ContentView instead you map view and attach / detach map view to / from it